Flutter repeatative schedule local notification
I am trying to implement the local notification in flutter where user set the notification coming days like coming in sunday, monday and tuesday , and then user set the time range like between 4-5pm and finally user set the interval of time in which notification/alert comes like every 5 minutes. So the notification should come in selected days only and selected time range and in every interval time gap.
void generateAndScheduleNotifications() {
    hiveController.retrieveCustomMinute();

    DateTime start = convertTimeOfDayToDateTime(startTime).toUtc();
    DateTime end =
        convertTimeOfDayToDateTime(endTime).toUtc().add(Duration(days: 30));

    print('Generating daily notifications for days: $selectedDayNames');

    final rule = RecurrenceRule(
      frequency: Frequency.daily,
      until: end,
      byWeekDays: selectedDayNames,
    );

    final instances = rule
        .getInstances(
            start: DateTime.utc(start.year, start.month, start.day, start.hour,
                start.minute, start.second))
        .toList();

    final dates = instances
        .map((instance) =>
            tz.TZDateTime.from(instance, tz.getLocation('Asia/Kathmandu')))
        .toList();

    print('Daily dates to schedule: $dates');
    _scheduleDailyAndMinutelyNotifications(dates);
  }

  Future<void> _scheduleDailyAndMinutelyNotifications(
      List<tz.TZDateTime> dailyDates) async {
    DateTime end = convertTimeOfDayToDateTime(endTime);

    for (final dailyDate in dailyDates) {
      DateTime endDate = DateTime(dailyDate.year, dailyDate.month,
              dailyDate.day, end.hour, end.minute, end.second)
          .toUtc();

      // Schedule the daily notification
      await _scheduleDailyNotification(dailyDate);

      // Schedule the minutely notifications for that day
      await generateAndScheduleMinutelyNotifications(dailyDate, endDate);
    }

    print('All notifications scheduled.');
  }

  Future<void> _scheduleDailyNotification(tz.TZDateTime dailyDate) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      dailyDate.hashCode, // Use a unique ID for each daily notification
      'Scheduled Notification',
      'Daily notification for ${dailyDate} (${DateFormat('EEEE').format(dailyDate)})',
      dailyDate,
      const NotificationDetails(
        android:
            AndroidNotificationDetails('your_channel_id', 'your_channel_name'),
      ),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime,
    );
    print('Daily notification scheduled for $dailyDate');
  }

  Future<void> generateAndScheduleMinutelyNotifications(
      tz.TZDateTime dailyDate, DateTime endDate) async {
    DateTime start = dailyDate.toUtc();

    print('Generating minutely notifications from $start until $endDate');

    final rule = RecurrenceRule(
      frequency: Frequency.minutely,
      until: DateTime.utc(endDate.year, endDate.month, endDate.day,
          endDate.hour, endDate.minute, endDate.second),
      interval: 1,
    );

    final instances = rule
        .getInstances(
            start: DateTime.utc(start.year, start.month, start.day, start.hour,
                start.minute, start.second))
        .toList();

    final dates = instances
        .map((instance) =>
            tz.TZDateTime.from(instance, tz.getLocation('Asia/Kathmandu')))
        .toList();

    print('Minutely dates to schedule: $dates');

    await _scheduleNotifications(dates);
  }

  Future<void> _scheduleNotifications(List<tz.TZDateTime> dates) async {
    for (final date in dates) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        date.hashCode,
        'Scheduled Notification',
        'This is a scheduled notification for ${date} (${DateFormat('EEEE').format(date)})',
        date,
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'your_channel_id', 'your_channel_name')),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
      );
    }

    print('All notifications scheduled.');
  }


https://pub.dev/packages/rrule  demo here:  https://jkbrzt.github.io/rrule/

@Aks byWeekDays property is not working in rrule package. even if i not select some days like monday and tuesday, notification is coming in these days.

When you create an rrule then it'll gives List of occurrings. So, you need to create something like. If you are passing the startdate in the rrule then it should return you the next occurring. and all properties will work if it's showing the string correctly on rrule demo page. Someting like: "every week on Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday for 1 time"

`final rule = RecurrenceRule(
frequency: Frequency.daily,
until: start.add(Duration(days: 730)),
byWeekDays: [
ByWeekDayEntry(DateTime.tuesday),
ByWeekDayEntry(DateTime.thursday),
]);
final instances = rule
.getInstances(
start: DateTime.utc(start.year, start.month, start.day, start.hour,
start.minute, start.second))
.toList();
`
@Aks In above code notification is scheduled for only tuesday and thursday but notification is scheduled for others day also

When you try to print the list of instances. Check if it's correct or not like it should only show instances for tuesday and thursday. In my case the scheduling is android native side. So, I create an alarm with rrule and schedule the first instance only. When the alarm is ringing I extract the next occurrance from that alarm's rrule and schedule it and it'll work until the next occurrance is not null or empty or a valid time.

Yes, the instances of dates are coming in the correct pattern. I am testing the execution by manually changing the date and time for the upcoming days. However, even if there is no schedule for a particular day, the notification is still appearing.

May be they are already scheduled ? Try to uninstall app and reinstall once, and there's also a method in flutter_local_notification which will return you the list of already scheduled notifications.

may be that is not the case because notification for rrule is different in title and description from other notification.and also there is a function from which i can cancel all the local notification at once.so Iam using that.

@Aks Recently I use notification date and time in the description of the incoming notification. So I got that even if i change date and time manually, today's date is coming always but time varies.

Can you update the code in your question. So, I can try to run that on my side and check.

@Aks updated please check
